# GWTP - Identify when Presenter is removed from Slot

Tags: gwtp, gwt-platform

I want to add a confirmation popup when a user navigates away from one of my presenters and is replaced in a NestedSlot. Can I intervene before a place is revealed and check the current presenter?

Edit:  I just learned that the `PlaceManager` has some support for this using the `setOnLeaveConfirmation` method. That said, I still don't think this will work for my case because I want the confirmation popup to be associated with a single nested presenter.  I would also prefer to manually intervene because I already have a confirmation modal for a cancel button that I want to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been simple if you could override `window.confirm()` using GQuery the same way as you can in JQuery, however that's not the case. Your best option is still using `placeManager.setOnLeaveConfirmation()`. You could probably emulate the same behaviour as `window.confirm()` with a PopupWidget, but then it wont block access to other parts of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I played around with the setOnLeaveConfirmation() method but I wasn't able to set this up against one specific presenter and therefore I can't use it.